# nestjs env variable undefined before class definition

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables, nestjs

I am working on app written in `nestjs` and trying to implement `WebSocket`. One problem i am having is with use of `env` `variables`. In the `gateway` file where i define my `WebSocket` implementation we have need of using `PORT` from `env` before `class` is defined:

```
console.log(process.env.WSPORT) // undefined
setInterval(() => {
  console.log((process.env.WSPORT) // after few logs its becoming accessible
}, 100)
@WebSocketGateway(process.env.WSPORT)
export class ExportFeedsGateway implements OnGatewayInit {
```

I tried to debug what is going on, and it seems to be related with `when` it is invoked as few moments later this `variable` becomes available for use.

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ExportFeedsGateway } from './modules/exportFeeds/export-feeds.gateway';

@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({ expandVariables: true })],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService, ExportFeedsGateway],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

export-feeds.gateway.ts

```
import { OnGatewayInit, WebSocketGateway } from '@nestjs/websockets';

@WebSocketGateway(process.env.WSPORT)
export class ExportFeedsGateway implements OnGatewayInit {
    ...
}
```

how to modify this code to make sure that `WSPORT` is not undefined when its passed to `WebSocketGateway` `decorator`?

**----- EDIT**

I was hoping to utilise `nestjs` code to access this variable rather then use packages like `dotenv`

main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { WsAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-ws';

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
    app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));
    await app.listen(PORT);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did deeper research and the problem i was having is actually result of trying to use `WebSocket` implementation (gateway) as standalone import. So the answer and solution to the problem is to `create` module first

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ExportFeedsGateway } from './export-feeds.gateway';

@Module({
    providers: [ExportFeedsGateway],
    exports: [ExportFeedsGateway],
})
export class ExportFeedsModule {}
```

This is a proper way of doing things as far as `nestjs` is concerned.
After this step module should be imported instead of gateway and `env` variables are accessible through `process.env.something`

```
@WebSocketGateway(Number(process.env.EXPORT_FEEDS_PORT))
export class ExportFeedsGateway implements OnGatewayInit {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to inject that env var in the shell, not via `.env`. Or use the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) by yourself as the first line at your `main.ts`

Comment: I dont think its how you should access it in `nestjs`, I updated my question to include `main.ts` file, and there i use `process.env.PORT` which becomes available after `importing` `ConfigModule` and setting it up. So i was hoping for solution within `nestjs` workflow. If you inspect dependencies you can see that nest already uses dotenv inside its config module so there surely is a way to do it more properly

Comment: yeah, I know. But at the time that `process.env.WSPORT` is evaluated by nodejs, `@nestjs/config` hasn't been called `dotenv.config()` yet. You should either call `dotenv` by yourself or supply that `WSPORT` to the shell instead of via the `.env` file.
Follow what I said and you'll be fine, trust me :)